# Need to replace a URL on page using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some way to replace

https://stusys.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=0008&subject=LAG&term=202095

with

https://stusys.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=0008&subject=LAG&term=202090

using JS. The page is generated dynamically and now we need some one-off half-semester classes added.

Does anyone know how to swap these URLs with something I can just toss into the footer.

Comment: you want to replace this single url only with the given ?

Comment: and whats the code you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)():

```js
var url = new URL('https://stusys.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=0008&subject=LAG&term=202095')
url.searchParams.set('term', 100)
console.log(url)
```

Comment: Lawrence 

I tried dropping the code into this page but it's not working for some reason. Am I missing something or have it done it wrong.

https://www.harpercollege.edu/catalog/current/courses/lag.php#LAG-0008

Comment: what do you mean by dropping it into the page?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I fully understand your question, but if you just are going to replace the two URLs you can use the Javascript [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a script you can drop in to your page which will dynamically change some of the hyperlinks. Since your page is already loading jQuery, this should do the trick:

```
<script>
    $('a[href="https://stusys.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=0008&subject=LAG&term=202095"]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', 'https://stusys.harpercollege.edu/class-schedule/class-schedule.html?course=0008&subject=LAG&term=202090' )
    })
</script>
```